# developers tools in a chrome incognito mode in a separate window

Tags: google-chrome

I used to get developers tools in a seperate window @Chrome Incognito mode, but since last week, i realized I can't do it anymore.

It's still available in normal mode, but in incognito mode it's always move right and bottom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long Press the button that makes it move right and bottom

[image]